# Convert PDF to HTML file Java API

Tags: java, html, pdf

I want to convert a pdf file to html file using java application. The PDF file contains some images , text etc.  Doesn anybody know a good java API? (please don't suggest Aspose).
I tried Apache PDFBox but not satisfied

Comment: I can't suggest a library, but some general advice: PDF to HTML is not trivial. They are two very different formats and any conversion will depend strongly on the quality and structure of the PDF. Alone the extraction of the text in the right order can be tricky. Let alone the formatting and layout. Often a manual conversation will be the best practical solution. May be the bigger picture would help giving more detailed help: How many PDFs? Did you make them yourself? Or general: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 10):

[CSSBox Pdf2Dom](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/pdf2dom) is a Java library that allows (among other things) converting PDF to HTML. The distribution contains even a [PDFToHTML](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/pdf2dom/download.php) command line tool based on this library so you can check if the results correspond to your needs. However, converting PDF to HTML is always tricky as noted above. The results depend on the complexity and the structure of the particular PDF file so different tools may be suitable for different PDF files.

Comment: FYI for future searchers on Pdf2Dom: it works well but uses an absolute positioning technique for the output HTML. Which means: it is very good at reproducing the look of the content, but if you want to do something programmatically with the output, its not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Check out

[JPedal](http://www.idrsolutions.com/pdf-to-html5-conversion/), it handles embedded fonts very well but not free.

[IcePDF](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEpdf/overview.jsf), it is free but afaik it only can extract text/images or render the PDF to an image.

```
public class QHyperArticleHtmlBuilder extends QHtmlBuilder {
    QStyle anchorStyle = createStyle("anchorStyle", a);
    QStyle sectionStyle = createStyle("sectionStyle", div);
    QStyle subsectionStyle = createStyle("subsectionStyle", div);
    ...    
    public String buildSubSectionHeading(String anchorName, String text) {
        return buildAnchorHeading(subsectionStyle, anchorName, text);
    }

    protected String buildAnchorHeading(QStyle divStyle, 
            String anchorName, String text) {
        QMutableElement element = create(p);
        element.add(br);
        element.add(create(a, anchorStyle, name.create(anchorName)))
        .add(create(div, divStyle, text));
        return element.buildHtml();
    }

    public String buildLink(String url, String label) {
        QMutableElement element = create(a, anchorStyle, href.create(url));
        element.add(create(span, underlineStyle))
        .add(create(span, linkStyle, label));
        return element.buildHtml();
    }
}


pre.javaStyle {
  font-family: courier new, courier, mono;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  font-size: 11pt;
  width: 800px;
  border: dashed 1px;
  border-color: lightgray;
  padding-left: 4px;
}
```

Resources [here](https://code.google.com/p/vellum/)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I want a open source api (not paid one). I din't considered aspose api , since it's not free.

Answer (score 1):

Try our Java library called jPDFWeb which preserves fonts and image resolution from the original PDF. You can upload your own PDF and try the live demo.

https://www.qoppa.com/pdfhtml/

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use Print2Flash: www.print2flash.com It can convert to HTML from Java not only pdfs but other kinds of documents as well: Office docs, AutoCAD drawings, etc. It solved all document publishing needs for our company web site.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps you can use this API: https://market.mashape.com/netservice/convert-pdf-to-html 
works for java, node, php etc...

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: links to an api that does not work or does not have documentation.